# Add array elements to list

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to append array elements to the list using below code:

```
function GetList() {
let list = [];
$.ajax({
    url: '../Lookup/GetList',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        debugger;
        
        list = response;

        //for (var data in response) {
        //    list = { value: data, rest: list };
        //}
        //for (let i = response.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //    list = { value: array[i], rest: list };
        //}
        //for (let i = response.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //    list.push(response[i]);
        //}                         
    }        
});
return list;
}
```

I have attached the screenshot of array data format.
I need in the below list format:

```
var list= [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "LookupMasterName": " Source1",
    "Description": "xxx",       
    "Enabled Flag":"Y"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "LookupMasterName": " Source2",
    "Description": "yyy",        
    "Enabled Flag": "Y"
  }    
];
```

Above code doesn't work. It returns empty list. Can you help?

[image]

Comment: This is not C#, please remove the C# tag

Comment: What does "doesn't work mean"? Error? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: There is no evident error here.

Comment: Space is not allow in key name. You have to remove space like LookupMasterName, LMN something like that

Comment: This works, I just tried it

Comment: @Hkachhia, space is allowed since it's a string

Answer (score 0):

It's returning an empty list because this line `return list;` is executed before Ajax is completed. A solution to fix it is wrapping your Ajax request into a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

Example:

```
function GetList() {
  let list = [];
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: "../Lookup/GetList",
      type: "GET",
      cache: true,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
        list = response;
        resolve(list);
      },
    });
  });
}
```

Then calling `GetList`:

```
GetList().then(list => /* do whatever you need */)
```

Comment: tried above, it is also returning in the list format

Comment: Does it work? don't forget to use also `rejects` in case your request fails